# I am trying to create the nodes using Cypher with the counter

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I am trying to create the nodes using Cypher with the counter how can I do it? I did not find anything helpful in documentation is there anyone who came across this case?

Comment: Welcome, you will need to add more details to what you are trying to do and what's not working for you. The current post is unfortunately too vague.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have node named User and I wanted to create a property named "counterId". This is how I generated a counter from 1 to x where x is the number of all Users.

```
//collect all users in a list
MATCH (n:User)
WITH collect(n) as n_list 
//for each user, set the counterId to this counter i
FOREACH(i IN range(1, size(n_list)+1) | set (n_list[i-1]).counterId = i);
```